# R: how to get optim to output parameter values at each iteration

Tags: r, optimization, mle

```
library(stats4)
x <- 0:10
y <- c(26, 17, 13, 12, 20, 5, 9, 8, 5, 4, 8)

## Easy one-dimensional MLE:
nLL <- function(lambda) -sum(stats::dpois(y, lambda, log = TRUE))
fit0 <- mle(nLL, start = list(lambda = 5), nobs = NROW(y), method = "L-BFGS-B")
```

This is a toy example from `mle`'s documentation. The optimization method I chose to use is L-BFGS-B. I'm interested in seeing the `lambda` values at different iterations.

Looking into `optim`'s help page, I tried adding `trace = TRUE`. But that seems to give me the likelihood at each iteration and not the `lambda` values.

```
> fit0 <- mle(nLL, start = list(lambda = 5), nobs = NROW(y), method = "L-BFGS-B", control = list(trace = TRUE))
final  value 42.726780 
converged
```

How can I obtain the `lambda` estimates at each iteration?

Comment: If you just want to see lambda and not to keep it in a vector, add `print(lambda)` into `nLL`